# Lowest value in 1:n as next row

Tags: r

This problem has two main inputs, a data frame containing two columns Value1 and Value2; and a vector (n) containing a value bigger than 0 and smaller or equal than 15.
The raw data can be seen below.

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 2.29608704283624 | 178.5 |
| 2.06086811023972 | 161.5 |
| 1.87079827663778 | 169.1 |
| 1.86275821684203 | 192.5 |
| 1.85448251414627 | 29.5 |
| 1.83986464224616 | 134.6 |
| 1.73638234842552 | 167.2 |
| 1.58625615251115 | 179.4 |
| 1.5752510727807 | 172.5 |
| 1.56489899541047 | 165.6 |
| 1.55963692389198 | 193.2 |
| 1.5576445805493 | 186.3 |
| 1.55032526063405 | 172.5 |
| 1.55032526063405 | 165.6 |
| 1.55032526063405 | 193.2 |

The first goal is to sort the data frame in descending order based on Value1.
Secondly, a new column (Value3) is created from a sequence of integers starting from 1:n, the sequence is then stored in Value3 rows.
Thirdly, rank Value2 rows from the minimum to highest value and then assign the result to a new column Value4.

I'm able to do this part no problem with the help of a for loop.

```
n <- 5
df <- df[order(-df$Value1),]

for(i in 1:length(df$Value1)){
  df$Value3[i] <- c(1:n)[i]
  df$Value4[i] <- rank(df$Value2[1:rig_count],ties.method = "min")[i]
}
```

After running the code above I obtain.

| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.29608704283624 | 178.5 | 1 | 4 |
| 2.06086811023972 | 161.5 | 2 | 2 |
| 1.87079827663778 | 169.1 | 3 | 3 |
| 1.86275821684203 | 192.5 | 4 | 5 |
| 1.85448251414627 | 29.5 | 5 | 1 |
| 1.83986464224616 | 134.6 |  |  |
| 1.73638234842552 | 167.2 |  |  |
| 1.58625615251115 | 179.4 |  |  |
| 1.5752510727807 | 172.5 |  |  |
| 1.56489899541047 | 165.6 |  |  |
| 1.55963692389198 | 193.2 |  |  |
| 1.5576445805493 | 186.3 |  |  |
| 1.55032526063405 | 172.5 |  |  |
| 1.55032526063405 | 165.6 |  |  |
| 1.55032526063405 | 193.2 |  |  |

As you can see above, after row 5, the row values for columns Value3 and Value4 are empty.

I'm attempting to add values in the next 5 rows (n = 5) for Value3.
column Value4 indicates in what order the rows of Value3 have to repeat.

In the case above, row 5 has the lowest value in column Value4 = 1 and Value3 = 5. Consequently, row 6 of column Value3 needs to have the same value as row 5.

The second lowest value in column Value4 is row 2; hence, row 7 of column Value3 needs to have the same value as row 2.

The third lowest value in column Value4 is row 3, row 8 of column Value3 needs to have that value.

Below is a image trying to explain the logic visually.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bapFo.png)

The output for dput() can also be seen below.

structure(list(Value1 = c(1.56489899541047, 1.39347110403037,
1.56265735991354, 1.54735564421237, 1.54735564421237, 1.47719949203161,
1.42333157685597, 1.5576445805493, 1.54735564421237, 1.58625615251115,
1.5752510727807, 1.55963692389198, 1.49796020755154, 1.49393654,
1.49393654, 1.52885306181508, 1.49033881372259, 1.54735564421237,
1.50780301071498, 1.55032526063405, 1.55032526063405, 1.48881946960588,
1.48782830698667, 2.06086811023972, 1.73638234842552, 1.86275821684203,
1.368960123448, 1.85448251414627, 1.87079827663778, 1.53151204713334,
1.30502454065456, 1.4636088118703, 1.14395137915335, 0.985375471907155,
2.29608704283624, 1.17245478295679, 1.03823643285323, 1.50632343329826,
1.33000855888495, 1.83986464224616), Value2 = c(165.6, 177.1,
193.2, 165.6, 193.2, 183.4, 184.8, 172.5, 179.4, 179.4, 172.5,
186.3, 28.4, 169.4, 184.8, 165.6, 174.9, 41.4, 179.4, 165.6,
193.2, 193.2, 55.2, 161.5, 167.2, 192.5, 23.6, 29.5, 169.1, 56.9,
171.1, 165.1, 202.9, 165.2, 178.5, 190.9, 83.6, 210.8, 176.3,
134.6)), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I don't understand this logic. `row 6 will have Value3 = 5 since it had the lowest Value2` how?

Comment: i don't quite get your logic... if we consider rows 6 to 11 you say row 7 has the second lowest value in its bracket in column 2 (value2), when obviously line 10 is lower (`165.6<167.2`) yet you want to label it 4 - which would be second highest by your logic. also please give us the data in a way we can easily reproduce (ie. `dput()`)

Comment: There is no logic explaining as to how you got your results

Comment: You said `Value3` is a sequence, from 1:n then said that it should be sorted. Is it not already sorted?

Comment: probably try `library(dplyr);df %>%
  group_by( gr = (row_number() - 1) %/% n)%>%
  mutate(Value3 = row_number(),
         Value4 = rank(Value2, ties.method = 'first'))`

Comment: Hi guys, I've edited the question a bit for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this close to what is wanted?

```
library(Rfast)

df <- structure(list(Value1 = c(1.56489899541047, 1.39347110403037, 1.56265735991354, 1.54735564421237, 1.54735564421237, 1.47719949203161, 1.42333157685597, 1.5576445805493, 1.54735564421237, 1.58625615251115, 1.5752510727807, 1.55963692389198, 1.49796020755154, 1.49393654, 1.49393654, 1.52885306181508, 1.49033881372259, 1.54735564421237, 1.50780301071498, 1.55032526063405, 1.55032526063405, 1.48881946960588, 1.48782830698667, 2.06086811023972, 1.73638234842552, 1.86275821684203, 1.368960123448, 1.85448251414627, 1.87079827663778, 1.53151204713334, 1.30502454065456, 1.4636088118703, 1.14395137915335, 0.985375471907155, 2.29608704283624, 1.17245478295679, 1.03823643285323, 1.50632343329826, 1.33000855888495, 1.83986464224616), Value2 = c(165.6, 177.1, 193.2, 165.6, 193.2, 183.4, 184.8, 172.5, 179.4, 179.4, 172.5, 186.3, 28.4, 169.4, 184.8, 165.6, 174.9, 41.4, 179.4, 165.6, 193.2, 193.2, 55.2, 161.5, 167.2, 192.5, 23.6, 29.5, 169.1, 56.9, 171.1, 165.1, 202.9, 165.2, 178.5, 190.9, 83.6, 210.8, 176.3, 134.6)), row.names = c(NA, 40L), class = "data.frame")
df <- df[order(-df$Value1),]
m <- matrix(df$Value2, 5)
df$Value3 <- c(1:5, colOrder(m[,-ncol(m)]))
df$Value4 <- as.integer(colRanks(m))
print(df, row.names = FALSE)
#>     Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
#>  2.2960870  178.5      1      4
#>  2.0608681  161.5      2      2
#>  1.8707983  169.1      3      3
#>  1.8627582  192.5      4      5
#>  1.8544825   29.5      5      1
#>  1.8398646  134.6      5      1
#>  1.7363823  167.2      2      3
#>  1.5862562  179.4      3      5
#>  1.5752511  172.5      1      4
#>  1.5648990  165.6      4      2
#>  1.5626574  193.2      1      4
#>  1.5596369  186.3      5      3
#>  1.5576446  172.5      2      2
#>  1.5503253  165.6      4      1
#>  1.5503253  193.2      3      4
#>  1.5473556  165.6      4      3
#>  1.5473556  193.2      3      5
#>  1.5473556  179.4      2      4
#>  1.5473556   41.4      1      1
#>  1.5315120   56.9      5      2
#>  1.5288531  165.6      4      2
#>  1.5078030  179.4      5      4
#>  1.5063234  210.8      1      5
#>  1.4979602   28.4      3      1
#>  1.4939365  169.4      2      3
#>  1.4939365  184.8      4      4
#>  1.4903388  174.9      1      2
#>  1.4888195  193.2      5      5
#>  1.4878283   55.2      2      1
#>  1.4771995  183.4      3      3
#>  1.4636088  165.1      4      2
#>  1.4233316  184.8      2      5
#>  1.3934711  177.1      5      4
#>  1.3689601   23.6      1      1
#>  1.3300086  176.3      3      3
#>  1.3050245  171.1      4      3
#>  1.1724548  190.9      1      4
#>  1.1439514  202.9      5      5
#>  1.0382364   83.6      3      1
#>  0.9853755  165.2      2      2
```

Comment: This is doing exactly what I need! However, depending on the value for n (i.e 3, 6, and 7) I get the following warning/error. Warning message for n = 6
In matrix(df$DrillingGroupDrillingDays, rig_count) :
  data length [40] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [6] and Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, AssignedRig, value = c(1L, 2L, 3L,  : 
  replacement has 42 rows, data has 40